# how to get file from library which stored in unknown folder( need c# csom)

Tags: development, csom, caml-query

I have library which has many folders and I have file name and want to find using name of the file from those folders (dont know in which folder that file placed). please help to write code using c# csom.

Note: library has crossed threshold limit.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Search API on CSOM and Use KeywordQuery syntax to restrict a particular document library and filename. This will take care of your threshold and you don't have to iterate all the folders to find a document.

For your scenario you would have to use

```
filename:budget.xlsx
PATH:http://hogwarts.com/sites/firstyear/Gryffindor*
```

For details on keywords syntax 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff394509(v=office.14)

Fore details on using CSOM for Search - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/using-the-sharepoint-search-query-apis

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for your reply, Yes I tried your suggestion and it worked however in my CAML query there were typo mistake hence for me both things are working. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped...please upvote and mark as answer for other's reference.